# Create multiple UITableView sections with rows from 2 NSMuteableArrays

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I have two `NSMuteableArray`s. The first (nameOfSectionArray) collects the name of each new section. The second (numberOfRowsArray) collects how many rows each section should have. I am having trouble using these arrays to create a `UITableView` that has the right number of sections with the right number of rows.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [nameOfSectionsArray count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [numberOfRowsArray objectAtIndex:section];
}


-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [nameOfSectionsArray objectAtIndex:section];
}
```

The program does not crash. I just don't get any rows. All the sections come out properly. Could someone help me with my `numberOfRowsInSection` method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I realized that I was just creating an `NSMuteableArry` that would hold a number that said how many rows I had. In the future this would be a problem.

Instead I made another `NSMuteableArry` that I added an object for each row that I would have. Then I added this to the original numberOfRowsArray

This is what I did.

```
-(void) newRows
{

int i=0;
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *allCells = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

while (i<numberOfRows)
{
    [allCells insertObject:cell atIndex:[allCells count]];
    i++;
}

[numberOfRowsArray insertObject:allCells atIndex:[numberOfRowsArray count]];
}
```

then

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return [[numberOfRowsArray objectAtIndex:section] count];
}
```

This did the trick :)